# In SSMS is there a way to generate a script for table creation based on the table output by a view?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssms

In SSMS is there a way to generate a script for table creation based on the table output by a view?

Comment: I don't really understand the question. What I made of it is that you have a view, you select some data and would like to generate create statement to create a table that could hold that data. Is that what you want to achieve?

Comment: Exactly. Sorry after rereading my description it is a bit obtuse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no simple way of doing such a thing, because selected data is not sufficient to describe the table. Eg. there might be identity column and you won't know or some column may be nullable but actual data has no nulls and so on.

This is in general a complex task that requires a dedicated program, not an ordinary database management utility.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how, but the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7368864/retrieve-column-definition-for-stored-procedure-result-set) question may prove useful to you. It is concerning procedures, but the same principles might apply.