# T-SQL Detect the type of the columns that store procedure returns

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, detect, column-types

I am not going to deep into the details but I need a way to determined the type of the return columns by store procedure.

Is there a way to achieved that and I do not look for a solution that works with specified procedure - I should be able to detect this in other procedure that receive as parameter other procedure's name.

I am using SQL Server 2012.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retrieve column definition for stored procedure result set](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7368864/retrieve-column-definition-for-stored-procedure-result-set)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL Server 2012 you can use [`sp_describe_first_result_set`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878602.aspx)

As the name implies this returns metadata about the **first** result set only returned by a stored procedure. Example below.

```
CREATE PROC Foo
AS
SELECT *
FROM sys.objects

GO

EXEC sp_describe_first_result_set @tsql = N'Foo'
```

Comment: Thanks, I am interesting in the first result set only and this solve my issue perfectly. Just wondered, is there a way to retrieve column types information from each result set?

Comment: @gotqn - Not possible in TSQL. You could do it from a language such as `C#` by actually executing the stored procedure and looking at the result sets returned.

Comment: Any other solution for previous versions of SQL?

Comment: @TravisWhidden - Not straightforwardly using just TSQL. You can [`SELECT ... INTO`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1228165/73226) a table then look at the structure of that. Or outside of TSQL you can `SET FMTONLY ON` then execute it and look at the structure of the resultset.