# Get alias column name of procedure in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

`I` am using system procedure as follow to get `Column Name` from procedure.

```
exec Sp_depends @procedure-name
```

but it is not returning alias column name.

I have following query in procedure.

```
SELECT ID, E_No As E_No, Case When E_SAL BETWEEN 10000 AND 50000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END E_ACTIVE
FROM E_MAST
WHERE E_SAL BETWEEN 10000 AND 50000"
```

I need all column , including alias column but i cannot return alias. 
How can i return alias column name from procedure?

current result is :

```
**name         type   updated selected  column**
dbo.E_MAST  user table  no      yes       ID
dbo.E_MAST  user table  no      yes       E_NO
dbo.E_MAST  user table  no      yes       E_SAL
```

i need this result  :

```
**name         type   updated selected  column**
dbo.E_MAST  user table  no      yes       ID
dbo.E_MAST  user table  no      yes       E_NO
dbo.E_MAST  user table  no      yes       E_SAL
dbo.E_MAST  user table  no      yes       E_ACTIVE
```

Comment: It's not very clear to me what you want. Can you provide an example of how it should work?

Comment: the above query is in procedure for ex. [dbo].[sp_getempsal]..

when i execute below query to get used column in procedure 

    Exec sp_depends 'sp_getempsal'

i can't get E_ACTIVE column name.

Comment: i return only 

ID
E_NO
E_SAL

but no E_ACTIVE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`sp_depends`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189487.aspx) stored procedure is used to

> Displays information about database object dependencies, such as the views and procedures that depend on a table or view, and the tables and views that are depended on by the view or procedure.

So it correctly identifies all the columns that your stored procedure depends on. `E_ACTIVE` is an alias, it's not a database object, so there cannot be a dependency on it.

---

You can also check this question and its answer: [Retrieve column definition for stored procedure result set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7368864/retrieve-column-definition-for-stored-procedure-result-set) to see how you can get the metadata about a stored proc.

Comment: Please also note that `sp_depends` will be removed in the future so better do not rely on it in new code.

Comment: thanks to reply dear.
have any alternative way to get that column name ?

Comment: See the question I linked in my answer.