# Use the result of a system stored procedure as a queryable table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, table-variable

*Note: the highest [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653714/how-to-select-into-temp-table-from-stored-procedure?rq=1) does not solve the problem for system stored procedures, but it's close. With help of the commenters, [I came to a working answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23327256/111575).*

Trying to use statements such as the following for [sp_spaceused](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188776.aspx), throws an error

```
SELECT * INTO #tblOutput exec sp_spaceused 'Account'
SELECT * FROM #tblOutput
```

The errors:

> Must specify table to select from.

and:

> An object or column name is missing or empty. For SELECT INTO statements, verify each column has a name. For other statements, look for empty alias names. Aliases defined as "" or [] are not allowed. Change the alias to a valid name.

When I fully declare a table variable, it works as expected, so it seems to me that the stored procedure does return an actual table.

```
CREATE TABLE  #tblOutput (
    name NVARCHAR(128) NOT NULL, 
    rows CHAR(11) NOT NULL, 
    reserved VARCHAR(18) NOT NULL,
    data VARCHAR(18) NOT NULL,
    index_size VARCHAR(18) NOT NULL,
    unused VARCHAR(18) NOT NULL)

INSERT INTO #tblOutput exec sp_spaceused 'Response'
SELECT * FROM #tblOutput
```

Why is it not possible to use a temp table or table variable with the result set of `EXECUTE sp_xxx`? Or: does a more compact expression exist than having to predefine the full table each time?

*(incidentally, and off-topic, [Googling for the exact term `SELECT * INTO #tmp exec sp_spaceused`](https://www.google.nl/search?q=SELECT%20*%20INTO%20#tmp%20exec%20sp_spaceused) at the time of writing, returned exactly one result)*

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/653714/how-to-select-into-temp-table-from-stored-procedure?rq=1

Comment: `DECLARE @tblOutputTable` [**STOP** doing this](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/04/table-variables-good-temp-tables-sql-2014/), use temp tables.

Comment: @Kermit: ok, but temp table or table variable, in both cases (in this example) require me to predefine the table. Also, for very small resultsets, or scratchpad queries, [I don't really see the difference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27894/whats-the-difference-between-a-temp-table-and-table-variable-in-sql-server) (and the first example uses a temp table anyway ;)

Comment: @Abel Just got done with SQL Saturday. Brent Ozar demonstrated that statistics on table variables are inaccurate, and table variables should be avoided.

Comment: @Kermit: I updated the question to use your suggested best practices. (@daniel, that's the same link you gave in the 1st comment)

Comment: @DanielE.: the solution in the linked question does not work with this stored procedure. It throws `The OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "(null)" supplied inconsistent metadata for a column. The name was changed at execution time.`.

Comment: did you use a correct conectionstring?

Comment: @DanielE.: yes, I can use any other SELECT-query, just not this one.

Comment: @DanielE.: solution finally found, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/23327256/111575. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DR: use [`SET FMTONLY OFF`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173839%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) with [`OPENQUERY`](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html#OPENQUERY), details below.

It appears [that the link provided by Daniel E.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653714/how-to-select-into-temp-table-from-stored-procedure?rq=1) is only part of the solution. For instance, if you try:

```
-- no need to use sp_addlinkedserver
-- must fully specify sp_, because default db is master
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(
   [SERVERNAME\SQL2008], 
   'exec somedb.dbo.sp_spaceused ''Account''')
```

you will receive the following error:

> *The OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "LOCALSERVER\SQL2008" supplied inconsistent metadata for a column. The name was changed at execution time.*

I found the solution [through this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7369118/111575), and [then a blog-post on OPENQUERY](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html#OPENQUERY), which in turn told me that until SQL2008, you need to use [`SET FMTONLY OFF`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173839%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). The final solution, which is essentially surprisingly simple (and easier to accomplish since there is no need to specify a loopback linked server), is this:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(
   [SERVERNAME\SQL2008], 
   'SET FMTONLY OFF 
   EXEC somedb.dbo.sp_spaceused ''Account''')
```

In addition, if you haven't set `DATA-ACCESS`, you may get the following error:

> *Server 'SERVERNAME\SQL2008' is not configured for DATA ACCESS.*

This can be remedied by running the following command:

```
EXEC sp_serveroption 'SERVERNAME\SQL2008', 'DATA ACCESS', TRUE
```

Comment: All mine needed was the SET FMTONLY OFF; added to my statement.  I think my connection was retaining that setting from previous OPENROWSET commands.

Thanks for pointing this out!  It was non-obvious at the time.

Answer (score 2):

We cannot `SELECT` from a stored procedure thats why `SELECT * INTO ..Exec sp_` will not work.

To get the result set returned from a store procedure we can `INSERT INTO` a table.

`SELECT INTO` statement creates a table on fly and inserts data from the source table/View/Function. The only condition is source table should exist and you should be able to Select from it.

Sql Server doesn't allow you to use `SELECT` from `sp_` therefore you can only use the `INSERT INTO` statement when executing a stored procedure this means at run time you can add the returned result set into a table and Select from that table at later stage.

`INSERT INTO` statement requires the destination table name, An existing table. Therefore whether you use a Temp Table, Table variable or Sql server persistent table you will need to create the table first and only they you can use the syntax

```
INSERT INTO #TempTable
EXECUTE sp_Proc
```

Comment: You say "you will need to create the table first". Indeed, but that's precisely the point of my question. I don't want to have to do that, with system sp's this can be very tedious to do, esp,. for ad-hoc queries.

Answer (score -1):

```
Using [YOUR DATABASE NAME]

CREATE TABLE [YOURTABLENAME]
(Database_Name Varchar(128),
DataBase_Size VarChar(128),
unallocated_Space Varchar(128),
reserved Varchar(128),
data Varchar(128),
index_size Varchar(128),
unused Varchar(128)
);

INSERT INTO dbo.[YOUR TABLE NAME]
(
    Database_Name,
    DataBase_Size,
    unallocated_Space,
    reserved,
    data,
    index_size,
    unused

)

EXEC sp_spaceused @oneresultset = 1  
--To get it to return it all as one data set add the nonresultset=1 at the end and viola good to go for writing to a table. :)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. It is recommended to give context to an answer, instead of just copying in a snippet of code. Thanks for the effort, but it does not answer the question, your code will create a new actual table in a database, which is not what my original question was asking about (instead, it tried to prevent that). Specifically, I wrote: _"does a more compact expression exist than having to predefine the full table each time"_... Maybe I am missing the point, but than, please edit your answer to clarify.