# Get stored procedure column names

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a stored procedure looking like this:

```
SELECT
    nTransactionId
    ,strInstrument
FROM dbo.Deals
```

I've read that for SQL Server 2012 I can use `sp_describe_first_result_set`, but is there any alternative for SQL Server 2008?

When I say I want the column names I mean `nTransactionId` and `strInstrument`. Even if the query doesn't return any result.

Many thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retrieve column definition for stored procedure result set](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7368864/retrieve-column-definition-for-stored-procedure-result-set)

Comment: @GarethD I can't use linked server for this.

Comment: In that case I am fairly sure you can't do it. As far as I know you 3 options: **1.** Upgrade to SQL Server 2012. **2.** Use a linked server (although it is only linking it to itself). **3.** Find a solution to the problem that doesn't require knowing the definition of the procedure result.

Answer (score 0):

For that purpose I mostly use :

```
SET FMTONLY ON;
```

> Returns only metadata to the client. Can be used to test the format of
>   the response without actually running the query.

Have a look here: [Sql Server SET FMTONLY (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173839.aspx)

This is what DataSet designer is using for example in order to get the parameteres of a procedure.